# Selecting timeuuid columns corresponding to a specific date

Tags: cassandra, cql

Short version: Is it possible to query for all timeuuid columns corresponding to a particular date?

More details:

I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE timetest(
  key uuid,
  activation_time timeuuid,
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY(key,activation_time)
);
```

I have populated this with a single row, as follows (`f0532ef0-2a15-11e3-b292-51843b245f21` is a timeuuid corresponding to the date `2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100`):

```
insert into timetest (key, activation_time, value) VALUES (7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e, f0532ef0-2a15-11e3-b292-51843b245f21, 'some value');
```

And I can query for that row as follows:

```
select activation_time,dateof(activation_time) from timetest where key=7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e
```

which results in the following (using cqlsh)

```
 activation_time                      | dateof(activation_time)
--------------------------------------+--------------------------
 f0532ef0-2a15-11e3-b292-51843b245f21 | 2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100
```

Now lets assume there's a lot of data in my table and I want to retrieve all rows where `activation_time` corresponds to a particular date, say `2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100`.

I would have expected to be able to query for the range of all timeuuids between `minTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100')` and `maxTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100')` but this doesn't seem possible (the following query returns zero rows):

```
select * from timetest where key=7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e and activation_time>minTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100') and activation_time<=maxTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100');
```

It seems I need to use a hack whereby I increment the second date in my query (by a second) to catch the row(s), i.e.,

```
select * from timetest where key=7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e and activation_time>minTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100') and activation_time<=maxTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:07+0100');
```

This feels wrong. Am I missing something? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

The CQL documentation discusses [timeuuid functions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/mobile/cql/cql_reference/timeuuid_functions_r.html) but it's pretty short on gte/lte expressions with timeuuids, beyond:

> The min/maxTimeuuid example selects all rows where the timeuuid column, t, is strictly later than 2013-01-01 00:05+0000 but strictly earlier than 2013-02-02 10:00+0000. The t >= maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000') does not select a timeuuid generated exactly at 2013-01-01 00:05+0000 and is essentially equivalent to t > maxTimeuuid('2013-01-01 00:05+0000').

p.s. the following query also returns zero rows:

```
select * from timetest where key=7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e and activation_time<=maxTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100');
```

and the following query returns the row(s):

```
select * from timetest where key=7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e and activation_time>minTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100');
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sure the problem is that cqlsh does not display milliseconds for your timestamps
So the real timestamp is something like '2013-09-30 22:19:06.123+0100'
When you call maxTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06+0100') as milliseconds are missing, zero is assumed so it is the same as calling maxTimeuuid('2013-09-30 22:19:06.000+0100')

And as 22:19:06.123 > 22:19:06.000 that causes record to be filtered out.

Comment: Outstanding! Thank you so much!!! That's exactly it. Unfortunately you can't pass dates with miliseconds into minTimeuuid or maxTimeuuid... but that's another problem... If I calculate the min/max timeuuids and pass them into the query it works a treat, e.g. `select * from timetest where key=7daecb80-29b0-11e3-92ec-e291eb9d325e and activation_time>f0532ef0-2a15-11e3-8080-808080808080 and activation_time<f05355ff-2a15-11e3-7f7f-7f7f7f7f7f7f;`

Comment: FYI: I've logged issue [CASSANDRA-6395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6395) on the apache jira to enable millisecond accuracy queries. Thanks @dimas, would never have spotted this problem without your help :-)

Comment: If I were you, I would not do my own timeuuid calculations in Java but would manipulate end time of the query instead (by advancing it to the next second and zeroing the millis) and then filter with time<minTimeuuid(endTimePlusOneSec)  (note min not max). Or alternatively, you can keep the seconds, set millis to 999 and then use time<=maxTimeuuid(endTimeWith999ms) (here it is max again).

Comment: Agreed. I had been writing tests based on ISO8601-format strings (not UUIDs) and they didn't quite match up with what was stored in the database (out by miliseconds as you suggested). The fundamental mistake I made was that my tests expected second-granularity dates. Even knowing this (thanks to your answer) I had no way of making sub-second queries - thankfully this is now possible thanks to [CASSANDRA-6395](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6395). All is well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to answer but as an additional addon to @dimas answer.
cqlsh (version 5.0.1) seem to show the miliseconds now

```
 system.dateof(id)  
---------------------------------
 2016-06-03 02:42:09.990000+0000
 2016-05-28 17:07:30.244000+0000
```